Obfuscating package using Pyarmor + Poetry Build does not seem to work
I want to obfuscate a package. My current file structure is:
game/
├── my_game/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── play_game.py
│   └── other modules and directories
├── pyproject.toml
└── README.md
└── testing
└── logging

My first thought was doing
pyarmor gen -O dist2 src/mypkg 

as mentioned here: https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/getting-started.html#distributing-the-obfuscated-package
Which translates in my case to:
pyarmor gen -O dist2 game/my_game 

This creates a dist2 folder in my 'game' folder.
I've been using Poetry build in my_game to create a package from the code in "my_game' (and not all the other folders). Running 'poetry build' while in the 'game' folder leads to the error:
Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file in /Users/cdeleau/games or its parents
which I guess makes sense...? After copy pasting the pyproject and readme file from my 'my_game' folder it does give me the error "No file/folder found for package poker-game"...
So I try to create the obfuscated thing inside the project... by doing
cd game
pyarmor gen -O dist2 my_game 

which creates it inside... I can now copy paste my pyproject and readme inside dist2 and poetry build does work! But if I try to use this package now, it will throw complaints like:
dlopen(/Paths////pyarmor_runtime_000000/pyarmor_runtime.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PyCode_NewWithPosOnlyArgs'
If I look into the zip file that gets created I can actually see that it doesn't take the pyarmor_runtime_000000 with it. So I've tried to include it by adding
[tool.poetry]
include = [
    "poker_game/**/*"
]

to my pyproject... but it would not include it. I've tried manually copy pasting the folder in and that also doesn't work... plus I'm not sure anymore if I'm solving the problem.
It is not pyarmor btw, if i obfuscate the whole thing and copy paste that, it works fine... but I'm pretty sure that if I want to share my code in a reliable way I need a whl file :S
